# redirect to previously access page using jsp and servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am developing a web application using jsp and servlet. 
I have given the user the right to search in my website without login but want them to get the appointment after login.
So how do i redirect the user to the previously accessed page after showing the login page on clicking for appointment link?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to save their last page in some database and then retrieve it.

Comment: @Panther, it will make much load on the server for just simply firing insert nd select queries

Comment: you want to user to go to login in page which we was last before the login. or to page which he was last during last login.

Comment: To the page he was accessing just before login...

Comment: then you can simply pass last page reference in url query parameter, either full url encoded. Or if you have limited page create a static map , each key refering one page. Pass that key as query parameter

Answer (score 0):

The *stateless* way to do this is to encode the URL of the previously accessed page as a URL query parameter to the login page. After a successful login, the login controller redirects to the URL that was provided.

You can also save the redirect destination in server state, but that is a lot more trouble than it is worth, especially if you ever need to scale the app behind a load balancer.

Comment: Do you know what a URL query parameter is? It's a ```key=value``` element in every URL. You need to use a URLEncoder class (there are a lot of them around) to encode the URL of the add appointment page, then add that as the value to a key like ```afterLogin```. The login controller looks for the ```afterLogin``` key, and if it finds it, does a request.redirect to the decoded version of the value.

Comment: I know about the key value pair but I haven't used the URLEncoder class...so can u just help me with that...